# Github checkout and commit pattern

Tags: github

I am working on a project that has the main branch and 2 child-branches. The 2 child branches are whats being deployed to clients

`child-branch A` has unique features for client A 
`child-branch B` has unique features for client B 
`main` contains features that both `child-branch A` and `child-branch B` share.

Our initial suggested Git workflow is as follows:

1. If there is a fix or feature that should be shared by both child-branches, we should `git checkout` from the `main` branch, then once done merge the changes back to `main`, and the child branches then do a `git merge` with main.
2. If there is a fix or feature specific to `child-branch A or B`, then a `git checkout` is done on the specific child branch is made and pushed back to that branch only.

My question is that what are the pitfalls with this workflow, and what are the suggested alternatives? And also where is a good source of information on such workflow patterns?